# Why isn't this regex working?

Tags: regex, groovy

Regex works fine [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), but my script gets choked up on the underscores when I run it.  The underscores should not need to be escaped... What is the deal?

Just trying to grab any leading/trailing `$` and `_`:

```
def someString1 = "__test"
def someString2 = "$test"
def someString3 = "test_"
def someString4 = "$test_"

//...

    def matcher = someString1 =~ /([\$_]*)(.+?)([\$_]*)/
```

Using Netbeans as my IDE and the coloring of the regex indicates it thinks the underscores are variables.  Same is true if the dollar signs are escaped or not escaped.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The express `$_` in regex is a back-reference for the entire input string.  Try changing your regex to this:

```
([_\$]*)(.+?)([_\$]*)
```

Comment: Yeah, order doesn't matter... Don't know why I didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the $ is a [String and GString](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString) placeholder in groovy.  Since you are using groovy to do the regex, you will have to escape anything that follows a $ or I am sure its possible hard code the expression in a string..

```
def matcher = someString =~ /([\$\_]*)(.+?)([\$\_]*)/
```

Comment: Looks like the first way is the way to go.  I had actually tried that way already too, but apparently I have another problem holding me up.  The second way doesn't seem to work at all.